# Magento 2: On product page HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, error, product-attribute, http-error-500

System: Magento 2.1

Everything was running fine 5 minuts ago. I had 3 Products in my Catalog (all using the same Attribute Set). Then I simply  deleted 2 Attributes from my (currently in use) Attribute Set via Admin Panel. Then via Magento CLI I did `cache:clean` , `cache:flush`, `indexer:reindex`  -> then Deleted Browser Cache.

In Browser I reloaded my webshop (everithyng looks fine). When I click on a Product -> Product Page `https://myshop.de/product1-300x200.html`  loads and gives 
 `HTTP ERROR 500`.

Everything else on my Webshop works fine, just all my Product Pages give me the same `HTTP ERROR 500` error.

Comment: Did you check the error logs?

Comment: updatedmy question with error log content

Comment: Is there the exception log?

Comment: Yes, but exception.log was last updated on 22.December2016. My Problem has occured today, yesterday everything was perfekctly working. It occured when I deleted 2 Attributes from my active Attribute Set

Comment: You should enable error reporting : `app/bootstrap.php` -> `ini_set('display_errors', -1)`

Comment: You are the best My Friend ! after enabling error reporting I know the issue. It came from a `customAttr1.phtml` where I tried to access my custom attribute, which does not exist, because I deleted it. Just need to delete/edit some files

Comment: Yeah! I leave my answer below. I think it's really helpful for our community.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the unexpected error (e.g 500), we should enable error reporting on the bootstrap:

**app/bootstrap.php**

```
ini_set('display_errors', -1) // Should enable error reporting with -1 value.
```

In your case, we need to check the places where you call your custom attributes which have been deleted.

Another way, we need to check the Apache error log.

Comment: Thanks mate.. I was checking logs for last one hour.. Now I got the issue..

Comment: thanks man that helps alot

Answer (score 1):

Mostly "HTTP ERROR 500" occur due to code error or wrong file/directory permission. First you need to check/set proper permission and then enable error reporting to find actual error, after that you need to fix code/bug.

To enable error reporting

add following code at top after `php` tag `<?php` in `index.php` or `app/bootstrap.php` file

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```