# after changing admin language, cannot access admin page

Tags: magento2, admin, language, http-error-500

I have installed language extension and successfully installed on my test store. However, as soon as **I have changed the admin language and press save, the admin page crashed, giving 500 error and cannot access at all**. Frontend is still accessible.

I have deleted cache, but still not working.

I have contacted the developer, but if anyone has any idea how I could fix this, would be really appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Error Log:

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   iterator_to_array() must implement interface Traversable, null given
>   in /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Html/Calendar.php:86

Comment: Should enable error reporting: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/152218/33057

Comment: Do you have access of server's error log? If yes could please share any error that is logged into log file.

Comment: I enabled error reporting on bootstrap.php. But then what happens now? I tried accessing admin again, but don't see exception.log

Comment: now I see at the root of Magento installation error_log and it says 

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to iterator_to_array() must implement interface Traversable, null given in /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Html/Calendar.php:86

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again and again, for **the unexpected 500 error, we should enable error reporting on the bootstrap. Should enable error reporting with -1 value. That will report all PHP errors.**

Or need to **check web server log**.

**app/bootstrap.php**

```
ini_set('display_errors', -1) // Should enable error reporting with -1 value.
```

---

In your case, I'm not sure if it is a Magento bug or not. The locale Data may get the null value. Read more: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5356

A temporary solution, 
go to this file: `vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Html/Calendar.php` line ~65

Replace:

```
$localeData = (new DataBundle())->get($this->_localeResolver->getLocale());
```

With:

```
$localeData = (new DataBundle())->get('en_US');
```

Comment: Admin is working again! Thank you so much. Actually now the admin language is also the one I have changed to.
Is it ok to keep the error reporting on the bootstrap enabled? Or only when 500 error occurs?

Comment: @rtk0407 when 500, blank page, you should enable the error reporting to see more errors. From my experience, we should enable it when developing.